# Java: How do I write a generic method?

Tags: java, generics

let's say that I have several `Creature` subclasses, and that they have each have some sort of `getGroup()` method that returns a `List<Creature>`.

What I mean by *"some sort of"* `.getGroup()` method is that the name of this function varies between subclasses.  For instance, `Wolf`s travel in packs, so they have a `getPack()` member.  `Fish` travel in schools, so they have a `.getSchool()` member, `Humans` have a `getFamily()` member, and so on.

**`.getGroup()` doesn not exist in `Creature`, and it cannot be added to the interface.  None of these clases can be edited.**

I'm writing a method to print the number of `Creature`s in their group. How would I do this?

Essentially, I'm looking to condense these two functions into the same thing:

```
    public void PrintSchoolSize(Fish dory) {
        System.out.print(dory.getSchool().size());
    }

    public void PrintHiveSize(Bee bee) {
        System.out.print(bee.getColony().size());
    }
```

...into the following function:

```
    public void printGroupSize( Class<? extends Creature> cree, 
                                FunctionThatReturnsList getGroup() ) {
        System.out.print(cree.getGroup().size();
    }
```

I'd imagine I need to pass in a second argument (function pointer?) to `void printGroupSize`. Any help is very appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT  Thank you all for the help.  This is just a simplification of the *real* problem I'm trying to solve.  Long, overly complex problems are tougher to answer, so I posed this simpler scenario.**

**The only answer lies in using a generic function (if that exists).**  The classes I'm actually working with don't have a common interface, but they all have a function that returns a List.

Comment: You have to make a method in `Creature` that they all override.

Comment: `.getGroup() doesn not exist in Creature, and it cannot be added to the interface` why? Then what *does* the interface have?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Unfortunately for me, @Override isn't an option.  The question I posed is just a easy-to-ask simplification of a bigger problem I'm trying to solve.  The most optimal solution relies in generic functions

Comment: The clean approach is adding the generic `getGroup` method to `Creature`, override it in each class and then – if so you desire – implement the `get…` method in terms of it (or vice versa).  The ugly solution is to use reflection and some string naming the “group” to figure out what method to invoke but doing this is asking for trouble.

Comment: What you're describing are not generic functions in the Java sense of the term.  What do *you* mean when you say that?

Comment: If you cannot change the Creature interface why not add another interface called Groupable that defines the getGroup() method and have all your creatures implement that?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.  The only solution to my actual problem lies in generic methods, since the Classes I'm working with don't actually have a common interface.  I'm going to look at Class.getMethod()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the help.  Since I'm **not allowed to edit** any of the aforementioned classes/interfaces (I can only write external functions), I wrote the following function

```
  public List<? extends Creature> getGroup(Object obj) {

      if(obj.getClass() == Bee.class)
          return ((Bee)obj).getColony();

      if(obj.getClass() == Fish.class)
          return ((Fish) obj).getSchool();

      /* repeat for the other classes */

      return null;
  }
```

...and used it here, as so:

```
   public void printGroupSize( Class<? extends Creature> cree ) {
       System.out.print(getGroup(cree).size());
   }
```

I have verified that this solution does indeed work, since all of the get*****() functions return a `List<Creature>`.  This solution also shrinks my codebase significantly, and is easier to maintain than the current structure.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe in your question is not much related to Java's sense of "generic methods".  You could implement it with reflection (see Class.getMethod()), but I promise you that you really don't want to go there.

It would be better for `Creature` to declare a possibly-`abstract` method `getGroup()` that each subclass would override.  You may do that in addition to providing methods with subclass-specific names, if you wish.  Code that wants to obtain the group (or its size) without knowing the specific type of creature would invoke that creature's `getGroup()` method.  That's an application of *polymorphism*, which seems to be what you're actually after.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'll look into Class.getMethod(), since that seems like the solution I'm actually looking for.

Comment: @JayFrizzle, as you wish.  I mentioned `Class.getMethod()` because it indeed does seem to correspond to what you *asked*, but I have to reiterate that a reflective solution involving that method is unlikely to be what you *want*.  I urge you to instead shift to a better design.

Answer (score 0):

If getGroup cannot be added to the Creature interface why not add another interface to your creatures?

```
public interface HasGroup {
    Group getGroup();
}
```

Would mean you can create the method:

```
public void printGroupSize(HasGroup cree) {
    System.out.print(cree.getGroup().size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to had a `getGroup()` method to the `Creature` interface and implement it in each subclass, but it seems you cannot do that.

If you can modify the subclasses, I would actually create a new interface `CreatureGroupable` with a `getGroupSize()` and/or `getGroup()`. Each subclass of `Creature` shall implement this interface, e.g.

```
public interface CreatureGroupable {
   CreatureGroup getGroup();
}

public enum CreatureGroup {
   WOLF_PACK("pack", 30), 
   GEES_FLOCK("flock", 20),
   FISH_SCHOOL("school", 1000),
   HUMAN_FAMILY("family", 4),
   ...
   private final String name;
   private final int size;

   private CreatureGroup(String name, int size) {
     this.name = name;
     this.size = size; 
   }

   public String getName() { return name; }
   public int getSize() { return size; }
}

public class Wolf implements Creature, CreatureGroupable {
   // methods from Creature, constructor, ...

   public CreatureGroup getGroup() {
      return CreatureGroup.WOLF_PACK;
}
```

This way, if you have a `List<Creature>` you can access the group of each one and do whatever you have to do, e.g.

```
public void printGroups(List<Creature> creatures) {
   for (Creature c : creatures) {
      CreatureGroup group = c.getGroup();
      System.out.println("A " + group.getName() + 
                         " has roughly " group.getSize() + 
                         " individuals.");    
   }
}
```

If you want more flexibility, you may not use an `enum` and just a standard `interface` and `class` hierarchy for the groups.